# How to iterate repetitive rows in table to calculate count and show the sum

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, query, repeat

I am new to vf tables and repeat tags. i am trying to create the below table in vf page could anyone please help me to achieve this by telling the way how i can  do the below:-

**Object- Family**

```
Fields- GrandParent,Parent,Child,Weight,Workout_Hours
```

**Records:-**

```
GrandParent  Parent  Child  Weight height
GrandParent1 Parent1 Child1  30       2
GrandParent1 Parent1 Child2  25       1
GrandParent1 Parent2 Child1  10       1
GrandParent2 Parent1 Child1  30       3
GrandParent2 Parent2 Child2  20       2
```

**Expected Result-**

```
Parents          Weight            Workout_Hours
-----------------------------------------------------
GrandParent1    65                   4
------------
Parent1---------55---------------------3
  Child1             30                  2
  Child2             25                  1

Parent2---------10---------------------1
  Child1             10                  1

GrandParent2     50                  5
------------
Parent1----------30--------------------3
  Child1             30                  3

Parent2----------20--------------------2
  Child1             20                  2
```

Till now i have achieved to create parent column but in that teams and childs are getting repeated and i am also not sure how to calculate each repetitive childs and then show childs weight total in parent and the total of parents in grandparents weight.

**Page:-**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!MapGP }" var="grand">
    <tr><td>{!grand}<hr></hr></td></tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!MapGP[grand]}" var="par">
            <tr><td>{!par}</td></tr>
               <apex:repeat value="{!ChildMap[par]}" var="Child">
                 <tr><td>{!Child}</td></tr>
               </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

**Controller:-**

```
public List<Parent__c> tableData = [Select id,GrandParent__c,Parent__c,Weight__c,Workout_Hours__c from Parent__c];
        public Map<String,List<String>> getMapGP() {

          Map<String,List<String>> MapGP = new Map<String,List<String>>();
          for(Parent__c g : tableData)
          {  
                  if(MapGP.keyset().contains(g.GrandParent__c))
                  {
                     MapGP.get(g.GrandParent__c).add(g.Parent__c);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     MapGP.put(g.GrandParent__c,new List<String>{g.Parent__c});

                  }
          }

            return MapGP;
        }

        public Map<String,List<String>> getChildMap() {
         Map<String,List<String>> ChildMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();
          for(Parent__c g : tableData)
          {
            if(ChildMap.keyset().contains(g.Parent__c))
            {
               ChildMap.get(g.Parent__c).add(g.Child__c);
            }
            else
            {
                 ChildMap.put(g.Parent__c,new List<String>{g.Child__c});
            }

          }
          return ChildMap; 
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE and thanks for your nice question, see my answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could think of preparing data based on SOQL query using  [GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm)

I have replicated the data at my DE and following SOQL query is giving the exact formatting and summation which you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c, SUM(Weight__c), SUM(Workout_Hours__c) ,
GROUPING (GrandParent__c) grpGrantPt, GROUPING(Parent__c) grpPT
FROM Family__c
GROUP BY ROLLUP(GrandParent__c, Parent__c,Child__c)
ORDER BY GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c
```

**Query Result:**

[image: Group by rollup query result]

You just eliminate the first record as it is giving total summation.

**Controller**

Retrieve the records from SOQL query and store them into instance of wrapper class.

```
public class FamilyClass
{
    public List<FamilyData> lstFamilyRecord {get;set;}

    public PageReference displayData()
    {
        Boolean firstRecord = true;

        lstFamilyRecord = new List<FamilyData>();
         AggregateResult[] lstFamily = [SELECT GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c, SUM(Weight__c) weightTotal, SUM(Workout_Hours__c) whTotal ,
                                        GROUPING (GrandParent__c) grpGrantPt, GROUPING(Parent__c) grpPT
                                        FROM Family__c
                                        GROUP BY ROLLUP(GrandParent__c, Parent__c,Child__c)
                                        ORDER BY GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c];

        for(AggregateResult familyObj:lstFamily)
        {
            if(!firstRecord)
            {
                FamilyData wrapper = new FamilyData();
                wrapper.GrantParent = (String) familyObj.get('GrandParent__c');
                wrapper.Parent = (String) familyObj.get('Parent__c');
                wrapper.Child = (String) familyObj.get('Child__c');

                if(familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Child__c') !=null)
                {
                    wrapper.isChildRecord = true;
                }
                else if (familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Child__c') ==null)
                {
                    wrapper.isParentRecord = true;
                }
                else if(familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') ==null && familyObj.get('Child__c') ==null)
                {
                    wrapper.isGrantParentRecord = true;
                }
                wrapper.Weight = familyObj.get('weightTotal')!=null? ((Decimal)familyObj.get('weightTotal')).intValue():null;
                wrapper.WorkoutHours = familyObj.get('whTotal')!=null? ((Decimal)familyObj.get('whTotal')).intValue() :null;
                lstFamilyRecord.add(wrapper);
            }
            firstRecord = false;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class FamilyData
    {
        public String GrantParent {get;set;}
        public String Parent {get;set;}
        public String Child {get;set;}
        public Integer Weight {get;set;}
        public Integer WorkoutHours {get;set;}
        public Boolean isGrantParentRecord {get;set;}
        public Boolean isParentRecord {get;set;}
        public Boolean isChildRecord {get;set;}
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page id="familyPage" controller="FamilyClass" action="{!displayData}" showheader="true" sidebar="false"> 
    <table id="familytable" border="1"> 
        <tr>
            <th>Parents</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Work Hours</th>
        </tr>             
        <apex:repeat id="myRepeat" value="{!lstFamilyRecord}" var="key"> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText style="color: red;" value="{!key.GrantParent}" rendered="{!key.isGrantParentRecord}"/>
                    <apex:outputText style="color: blue;" value="{!key.Parent}" rendered="{!key.isParentRecord}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!key.Child}" rendered="{!key.isChildRecord}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!key.Weight}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!key.WorkoutHours}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>                       
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>          
</apex:page>
```

**Expected output**

[image: visualforce]

You can see only single `<apex:repeat/>` has been used to display the records in VFP which is more efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: yes, that's why I have experimented, you can see how clean the data is displaying

Comment: @cropredy, now based on the query, the logic become very simple, single repeat helps me to display data instead of 3 repeat statements

Comment: @Santanu - That was a nice explanation, but is it possible to make this whole table as a collapsible tree view so if the child data will be more can be shrink-ed so it will give the classy look to the table. Just like a Pivot table of Excel.