# How to make collapsible table in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have managed to achieve the below table but i wants to convert this table into the collapsible. can anyone please show me the way to achieve this.

Existing:-

[image]

Need to achieve:-

[image]

VF Page:-

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="FamilyClass" showheader="false">
  <!-- Include the Jquery Script files -->     
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.treeview.css')}"/>    
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>     
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.cookie.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>     
  <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Jtreeview,'Jquerytreeview/jquery.treeview.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- End of Javascript files --> 
  <script type="text/javascript">         
  $(function() 
  {             
  $("#tree").treeview({                 
  collapsed: false,                 
  animated: "medium",                 
  control:"#sidetreecontrol",                 
  persist: "location"            
  });          }) 
  </script>  <br/> <br/> <br/> 
  <!-- Tree --> 
  <div class="treeheader" style="height:0px;">&nbsp;</div> 
  <div id="sidetreecontrol">
  <a href="?#"><font style="color:blue;">Collapse All</font></a> | <a href="?#"><font style="color:blue;">Expand All</font></a>
  </div>  
  <ul id="tree">     
  <apex:repeat value="{!lstFamilyRecord}" var="key">         
  <li><strong><apex:outputtext style="color:blue;" escape="false" value="{!key.GrantParent}"/></strong>              
  <ul>                  
  <apex:repeat value="{!key.Parent}" var="Parent">                     
  <li><span class="formattextcon"><apex:outputtext style="color:green;" escape="false" value="{!Parent.Parent}"/></span>                         
  <ul>                             
  <apex:repeat value="{!Parent.Child}" var="gchildren">                                
  <li> <span class="formattextcon"> 
  <apex:outputtext escape="false" style="color:red;" value="{!gchildren.Child}"/></span> 
  </li>                      
  </apex:repeat>                        
  </ul>                            
  </li>                  
  </apex:repeat>                
  </ul>           
  </li>     
  </apex:repeat> 
  </ul> 
  <!-- End of Tree -->        
  </apex:page>
```

Controller:-

```
public class FamilyClass
{
    public List<FamilyData> lstFamilyRecord {get;set;}

    public PageReference displayData()
    {
        Boolean firstRecord = true;

        lstFamilyRecord = new List<FamilyData>();
         AggregateResult[] lstFamily = [SELECT GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c, SUM(Weight__c) weightTotal, SUM(Workout_Hours__c) whTotal ,
                                        GROUPING (GrandParent__c) grpGrantPt, GROUPING(Parent__c) grpPT
                                        FROM Family__c
                                        GROUP BY ROLLUP(GrandParent__c, Parent__c,Child__c)
                                        ORDER BY GrandParent__c, Parent__c, Child__c];

        for(AggregateResult familyObj:lstFamily)
        {
            if(!firstRecord)
            {
                FamilyData wrapper = new FamilyData();
                wrapper.GrantParent = (String) familyObj.get('GrandParent__c');
                wrapper.Parent = (String) familyObj.get('Parent__c');
                wrapper.Child = (String) familyObj.get('Child__c');

                if(familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Child__c') !=null)
                {
                    wrapper.isChildRecord = true;
                }
                else if (familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Child__c') ==null)
                {
                    wrapper.isParentRecord = true;
                }
                else if(familyObj.get('GrandParent__c') !=null && familyObj.get('Parent__c') ==null && familyObj.get('Child__c') ==null)
                {
                    wrapper.isGrantParentRecord = true;
                }
                wrapper.Weight = familyObj.get('weightTotal')!=null? ((Decimal)familyObj.get('weightTotal')).intValue():null;
                wrapper.WorkoutHours = familyObj.get('whTotal')!=null? ((Decimal)familyObj.get('whTotal')).intValue() :null;
                lstFamilyRecord.add(wrapper);
            }
            firstRecord = false;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class FamilyData
    {
        public String GrantParent {get;set;}
        public String Parent {get;set;}
        public String Child {get;set;}
        public Integer Weight {get;set;}
        public Integer WorkoutHours {get;set;}
        public Boolean isGrantParentRecord {get;set;}
        public Boolean isParentRecord {get;set;}
        public Boolean isChildRecord {get;set;}
    }

}
```

Comment: Please put code code whatever you have tried, rather than posting directly from this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164382/how-to-iterate-repetitive-rows-in-table-to-calculate-count-and-show-the-sum

Comment: @Santanu - Apologies for that but actually this is the exact same pattern what i was trying to implement that is why i have referred it as example. Now i am getting following Error: Unknown property 'String.Parent'